# I cannot println of joined table using grails

Tags: grails, join

I have three classes: 
Participants have many Sessions
Sessions have many Participants
Session_plan puts Participants and Sessions together

So, I want to query Session_plan and get a list of Sessions and their Participants but I'm not understanding how do it.  I've commented out the 'hasMany' and 'belongsTo' to make sure I'm at least getting data from the classes...and I am, but when I tried to put those back in and list the data (via a join, I don't get any data at all. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  Please advise.

```
package mytest
import mytest.Session_plan

class Sessions {
//static hasMany = [session_plan: Session_plan]
//static mapping = {
//session_plan indexColumn: [name: "session_id", type: String],
//  joinTable: [column: " sessio_id"]}
String session_id
String session_name
String session_tier

    static constraints = {
session_id(blank: false)
session_name(blank: false)
session_tier(blank: false)
    }
}


package mytest

class Session_plan {
//static belongsTo = Sessions
String session_id
String participant_id
Boolean authorization
Boolean step
Boolean limit
Sessions sessions
Particiipant particiipant
static embedded = ['sessions','particiipant']
static constraints = {
session_id(blank: false)
participant_id(blank: false)
authorization(blank: false)
step (blank: false)
limit(blank: false)
}
}

package mytest
class Particiipant {
//static belongsTo = Session_plan
String participant_id_type
String participant_id

    static constraints = {
participant_id_type(blank: false)
participant_id(blank: false)
    }
}


import grails.converters.JSON
import org.hibernate.Query
import org.hibernate.criterion.CriteriaSpecification
import mytest.Session_plan
import mytest.Sessions
import mytest.Participants

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

    // Check whether the test data already exists.
    …
    // Create data
    …

// Check to see if we have data in the tables
//def list = Sessions.executeQuery("select e from Sessions e, Session_plan ed where ed.session_id = e ")
//list.each { sessions->
//println "session_id = ${sessions.session_id}"
//}

//def results = Sessions.list()
//results.each { sessions->
//println "session_id = ${sessions.session_id}: session_name = ${sessions.session_name}; sessions_tier = ${sessions.sessions_tier}"
//}


  def list = Session_plan.list()
  results.each { session_plan->
  println "session_id = ${sessions_plan.session_id}"
  }
}
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

This lists my data but when I try to list the other fields like 'limit', nothing prints.

```
  def list = Session_plan.list()
  results.each { session_plan->
  println "session_id = ${sessions_plan.session_id}"
  }
```

I've been banging my head against the wall for two days now.  any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Isn't limit a  reserved word? it is always good to think around the issue you are dealing with. Lets ask.

If you wanted to limit the amount of records that was returned from your DB what would be a word used in your typical sql statement:

```
select * from somewhere where something like '%something%' limit 3;
```

Notice the word limit and yet you appear are attempting to  declare limit as a domain object.

Did your app actually start up ? mine on default HQL would not start due to this.

Whilst attempting to get this working I was over looking what you had going on in your domain classes and was wondering if you had either misunderstood the prinicipal of relationships or if there was a genuine reason such as nosql backend or something different to a typical relationships DB such as mysql/oracl/psql etc.

So perhaps this answer given all depends on the undefined what it is "you are running for the DB"

So far as HQL I tried this and it worked:

My bootstrap with dummy info:

```
import customshiro.Particiipant
import customshiro.UserSession
import customshiro.SessionPlan

class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->

        UserSession session1 = UserSession.findOrSaveWhere(sessionId:'abc', sessionName:'firstSession', sessionTier:'tier1').save(flush:true)
        UserSession session2 = UserSession.findOrSaveWhere(sessionId:'bbc', sessionName:'secondSession', sessionTier:'tier2').save(flush:true)
        UserSession session3 = UserSession.findOrSaveWhere(sessionId:'ccc', sessionName:'thirdSession', sessionTier:'tier3').save(flush:true)
        println "--- 1 ${session1}"
        Particiipant p1 = Particiipant.findOrSaveWhere( participantIdType: 'normal', participantId:'participantId1').save(flush:true)
        Particiipant p2 = Particiipant.findOrSaveWhere( participantIdType: 'super', participantId:'participantId2').save(flush:true)
        Particiipant p3 = Particiipant.findOrSaveWhere( participantIdType: 'reg', participantId:'participantId3').save(flush:true)
        println "-- 2 $p1"
        println "---------------------------------------"
        def s1 = SessionPlan.findOrSaveWhere(authorization:true, step: true, userLimit:true, currentsession:session1, particiipant: p1 ).save(flush:true)
        def s2 = SessionPlan.findOrSaveWhere(authorization:true, step: true, userLimit:true, currentsession:session2, particiipant: p2 ).save(flush:true)
        def s3 = SessionPlan.findOrSaveWhere(authorization:true, step: true, userLimit:true, currentsession:session3, particiipant: p3 ).save(flush:true)
        println "-- 3 $s1"


    }
```

DomainClass Session:

```
package customshiro

class UserSession {

    static hasMany = [sessionplan: SessionPlan]

    String sessionId
    String sessionName
    String sessionTier

    static constraints =  {
        sessionId(blank: false)
        sessionName(blank: false)
        sessionTier(blank: false)
    }
}
```

Domain class SessionPlan:

```
package customshiro

class SessionPlan {

    Boolean authorization
    Boolean step
    Boolean userLimit
    Particiipant particiipant
    UserSession currentsession
    //static embedded = ['currentsession','particiipant']
    static constraints = {
        authorization(nullable: false)
        step (nullable: false)
        userLimit(nullable: false)
    }
}
```

DomainClass Participant:

```
package customshiro

class Particiipant {

    static belongsTo = SessionPlan
    String participantIdType
    String participantId

    static constraints = {
        participantIdType(blank: false)
        participantId(blank: false)
    }
}
```

TestController:

```
package customshiro

class TestController {

    def index() { 
        def results = SessionPlan.list()

        results.each { sp ->
            println "sessionId = ${sp.currentsession.sessionId}"
            println "sessionName = ${sp.currentsession.sessionName}"
            println "sessionTier = ${sp.currentsession.sessionTier}"
            println "participantId = ${sp.particiipant.participantId}"
            println "participantIdType = ${sp.particiipant.participantIdType}"

        }
        render "check console"
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/testrelations
sessionId = abc
sessionName = firstSession
sessionTier = tier1
participantId = participantId1
participantIdType = normal
sessionId = bbc
sessionName = secondSession
sessionTier = tier2
participantId = participantId2
participantIdType = super
sessionId = ccc
sessionName = thirdSession
sessionTier = tier3
participantId = participantId3
participantIdType = reg
```

The above information in regards to misunderstanding simple refers to the domain classes I have which has sessionId declared in the UserSession class and the sessionPlan class does not repeats these calls why else would you have the relationship if they contain duplicate information ? So in the case of the controller for each session.plan it then lists the currentsession.values and participant values.

If it had been a case of

```
SessionPlan {

   static hasMany = [ anotherclass: AnotherClass ]
```

Then in your loop

```
results.each { sp ->
   sp.anotherclass.each { nextClass ->
      //nextClass.fields here and now its looping hasMany relation 
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for any typos on mobile. Was thinking you had duplicate  fields and you had then embedded the tables. Still unsure as to why you needed all that and if you do shouldn't session plan simply extend sessions class therefore obtaining all its attributes plus it's new features. This now starts to make it a different architecture